# What is a 'good way' to think about inverse limit and Direct limit?

Tags: category-theory

I have started learning some basics of Category Theory.Currently i am trying to understand the concept of [Direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) and [Inverse Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) but i find this concept really hard to digest.

> Could some one explain me with some details the good idea to think about Direct Limit and Inverse limit in practice?

I have knowledge of subjects like Module Theory,Galois Theory,Commutative Algebra(at the level of Atiyah Macdonald),Basics of Lie Algebra and of course elementary topics like Group theory and field theory etc.

Comment: Have you seen the concept of a stalk in algebraic geometry?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: No sorry i have not seen that yet.

Comment: Ok, it might help if you give a bit more detail on your background, so people can pick examples that are more familiar to you.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: i have added some details regarding my backgroup,does this help to give examples?

Comment: If you read Atiyah--Macdonald, then you can see inverse and direct limits there!

Comment: @Alejo: I know the definition but i don't understand the concept properly.Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to understand the notion of direct limit and inverse limit? In what context have they come up?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: As i mentioned in my question i am learning some basics of category theory,i found this concept there but i don't understand the real idea behind it.Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, I **hate** the terms "inverse limit" and "direct limit", and much prefer to speak of limits and colimits (or directed limits and directed colimits, if that is meant instead).